# What fonts are most commonly used for iOS design?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, font-size

I am deep into designing my first iOS app and was curious as to which fonts are most commonly used (or the best). Also, what sizes are used for feed items, names, title, etc....

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for stackoverflow, but having said that here is a useful resource for seeing what fonts are available on which OS's [iosfonts.com](http://www.iosfonts.com/)

Comment: @Paul.s this has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System fonts (used by the OS everywhere by default) is Helvetica, and Helvetica Neue

I am not sure if you are looking for data on apps using non-system fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica is probably the most commonly used font and is usually their system default. I don't know if there is a best as that is opinion.

Comment: Note that Helvetica is used on devices without a Retina display. Helvetica Neue is used on devices with a Retina display.